# OpenLayers: how to access an event attribute value from WMS GetFeatureInfo

Tags: openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, events

My OpenLayers script tries to get some features values from a WMS (which is a shapefile), to open a page in function of the attribute value returned.

My problem is the following: 
- the code returns a GET which contains the html code for displaying a table with each parameter names/values, and the value do really correspond to the clicked polygon. I can print the same values from event.text
- event.features is empty!

Obviously that's not a proxy problem (since I get the values back). How can I fix the code to access the attributes values?

Here is the code:

```
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180,-90,180,90);
var options = {restrictedExtent:extent};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map-id", options);
var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Global Imagery",
        "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
        {layers: "bluemarble", isBaseLayer:false}
    );

var lmes=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "LMEs",
        "http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dd/geoserver/ocean/wms",
        {layers:'ocean:LME66', transparent:true, styles:'LMES_colors'},
        {isBaseLayer:false, opacity:1, singleTile:true, visibility:true}
    );
map.addLayers([lmes, imagery]);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();

function toggleRestrictedExtent() {
      if(map.restrictedExtent == null) {
        map.setOptions({restrictedExtent: extent});
      } else {
        map.setOptions({restrictedExtent: null});
      }
    }
    var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
       url:'http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/geoserver/ocean/wms',
       title:'identify feature by clicking',
       output:'features',

       eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
          console.log(event);
          console.log(event.features);
          console.log(event.text);
        }
       }
    });

map.addControl(info);
info.activate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `infoFormat` property of `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo` to something that OpenLayers can parse in order to create features. When no `infoFormat` property is set a default mime type of `text/html` is used, this is why `event.text` contains the HTML markup of a table.

Along with setting `infoFormat` you also need to set the `format` property which OpenLayers will use to parse the response from the server. So, in order to have an output of features you must:

1. Know what response formats the target WMS server supports (you can get this from the response to a `GetCapabilities` request
2. Set the `infoFormat` so OpenLayers sets the mime type to request
3. Set the `format` property to an `OpenLayers.Format` that can be used to parse the response

Most WMS servers will support common formats like GML and GeoJSON which are both supported well by OpenLayers. As an example, if the target server supported GML then you could use the following code to create the `WMSGetFeatureInfo` control:

```
var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: 'http://[server_url_here]',
    output: 'features',
    infoFormat: 'application/gml+xml',
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML,

    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event){
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.features);
            console.log(event.text);
        }
    }
})
```

You should now see an array of features as well as the raw GML response from the server.

Comment: I'm using geoserver, so it support GML, and the layer is queryable.