# Calculate edge length of a feature in layer WMS

Tags: openlayers, layers, features, measurements

How to calculate edge length of a feature and display the result on the corresponding edges in layer when clicking on that feature.

Looks like this:

[image]

This is my WMS layer:

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
        }),
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/myDB/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'myDB:myLayer', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            ratio: 1,
        }),
        visible: true,
        minZoom: 16,
 });
 map.addLayer(myLayer)
```

Comment: It is only possible if the WMS server supports GetFeatureInfo output in some vector format. Some servers do support GML. If you work with such a service you can capture the geometry and continue with measure https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks you, Im using GeoServer for my `layer`.  I mean calculate the edge of the existing `feature` in layer, not `LineString` or `Polygon` draw on the map

Comment: @TomazicM I'm sorry, but I don't have the code for it yet because I don't know how to do it yet

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for your suggestion. So how can I calculate edges  of `feature` in `WFS` layer like illustration in question?

Comment: I'd use turf.js for that

Comment: See [Leaflet Measure Path](https://github.com/ProminentEdge/leaflet-measure-path) Leaflet plugin.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks you. This is exactly what I was looking for, but I don't know about Leaflet, it would be good if there is a similar example using Openlayers. But I will try to learn about Leaflet.

Comment: @IanTurton I will try your suggestion. Any suggestion is good for me. Thank a lot.

Comment: Ups, sorry for Leaflet reference. Here is one for OL: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html

Comment: WMS may return a geometry. Check the GetFeatureInfo formats and try `text/xml` if it is supported http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp%3Astates&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/xml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-109.618920610%2C35.194203593%2C-100.7419674%2C44.0711567. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72712/openlayers-how-to-access-an-event-attribute-value-from-wms-getfeatureinfo

Comment: The best INFO_FORMAT (if supported) for returning a geometry is `application/json` https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo  OpenLayers has built in spherical methods to calculate length and area https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-image-forked-pfnq4v?file=/main.js there is no need for turf.js

Comment: @Mike Thanks Mike ♥. But i want to calculate the length of the individual edges of a feature and display them on the corresponding edges not the total length. How can i do that. Thanks you again!

Comment: Display the feature using the style function from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html